# Where were these posted?

Tags: situation

Here's a little bit of a puzzle I came across in the wild.  It's not too hard but I thought it was fun so I thought I'd share it.

I recently encountered this ancient screenshot:

[image]

When and where were these messages posted?

A complete answer will not only give the correct time and place, but also will explain what information provides that answer and why.  If I think you are missing part of the picture I'll leave a comment to let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The when is simple:

> The posting date is right there in the images - 7202nd September 1993.
>  For those not familiar with the [September That Never Ended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September) this is equivalent to 20th May 2013 in the more common Gregorian calendar.

And for the where:

> That "tastes like prion disease" meme has been endlessly duplicated, but not many places still use Eternal September dates, so as far as I can tell, the original is [post 153 of a long thread on 4-ch.net](https://4-ch.net/dqn/kareha.pl/1365955937/101-200)
> (Found by searching for `"tastes like prion disease" 1993-09-7202`)